# C++11 Regular Expression with one or more whitespaces

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Using regular expressions in C++11, I'm trying to detect single HTML tags that end in `/>` or `/ >`, such as `<br/>` or `"<hr/  >`.

With Boost, I used this regex string: `"<.*/\\s*>"`
It worked fine, but the C++11 regex module doesn't accept it.

So I have tried this code:

```
#include <regex>

bool IsSingle(string sTag) {
    string regex_str = "<.*/((\s)*)>";  // \s* zero or more whitespaces
    regex reg1(regex_str, regex_constants::icase);
    bool bb =  regex_search(sTag, reg1);
    return bb;
}
```

2 problems:

1) it raises an error warning:

> warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]

2) it doesn't work.

With sTag arguments such as `<br/>` or `<br/ >`, the function returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS: using C++11 with gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), and Nebeans IDE 8.0.2.
And the  module that comes when invoking:

## include

Comment: To be specific, which regex module are you using? If it's a very simple regex engine, you might just have to do `_+`, `[ \t]+` or similar.

Comment: @ a p Thanks! I edited the code, showing I'm using the <regex> module that comes with my C++11 on gcc version 4.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sequence of two characters to go into the regular expression, namely one backslash and an `s`. But you wrote

```
string regex_str = "<.*/((\s)*)>";
```

in your code. This means you are adding an escaped character (which is illegal as there is no `\s` allowed in a string), which is not what you want. You need to escape the backslash like this:

```
string regex_str = "<.*/((\\s)*)>";
//                        ^^ note two backslashes
```

With this, your string `regex_str` will then contain a single backslash as intended.

Comment: I had tried that but it doesn't work. It throws this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error`

Comment: To be more specific, the code you suggested compiles, but throws the above-mentioned error at runtime.

Comment: @Karpov Ah, I just saw you used GCC 4.8 - and you probably tried using the standard library's `<regex>`, right? It's not implemented in GCC 4.8, try 4.9 :)

Comment: ouch! I'll install 4.9,then ... but that's probably going to take a while, since 4.8 is the one that comes when using ap-get on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!